# How do I lock a SQLite database?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a trigger on a table that I dont want to trigger during specific contexts.

In order to do this, I plan on:

1. locking the database
2. dropping the trigger
3. performing my operations
4. adding the trigger
5. unlocking the database

Locking the database is necessary so that any operations that other threads attempt to perform will halt until the triggers are back in place. How do I do this from the C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform your work in [a transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) by using the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` SQL:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TRIGGER dbname.triggername;
(do other stuff)
CREATE TRIGGER ...;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sqlite3_db_config()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_config.html) with [`SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_TRIGGER`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbconfig_enable_fkey.html) to temporarily disable triggers.